# Extending TypeError

Tags: exception, error-handling, typeerror, php-7

PHP7 introduced the TypeError "exception" (I know it implements throwable rather than extends exception so it's not strictly speaking an exception, but they behave in essentially the same way as far as I can tell) which gets thrown if you enable strict mode for function parameter type hinting.

```
declare (strict_types = 1);

function square (int $val) : int
{
    return $val * $val;
}

var_dump (square ("123"));
```

The above code should throw a TypeError, which you can optionally catch and attempt to recover from or terminate execution, depending on what is the most appropriate course of action to take.

However, TypeError seems like it would be a bit too generic, and it would be nice if you were able to extend it to convey a bit more information about the failure that occurred:

```
class TypeNotIntError extends TypeError {} // Throw this when an int was expected
class TypeNotFloatError extends TypeError {} // Throw this when a float was expected
class TypeNotStringError extends TypeError {} // Throw this when a string was expected
// etc
```

It should be possible to extend TypeError like this because the PHP documentation doesn't state that it's a final class.  However, while you can extend TypeError there doesn't seem to be a mechanism that allows you to throw a child of TypeError without manually throwing one inside a function.  As a TypeError would already be thrown by the engine if you pass in an invalid parameter type, the ability to extend TypeError seems pretty limited to me.

Is it possible to tell PHP what sort of TypeError subclass a function/method should throw if passed an invalid parameter type?  If so, how?

Comment: It isn't. You could use a `try { } catch {}` block and throw your own error, though.